# How can we apply HA-proxy with clustering at openfire

Tags: openfire

I have a openfire server setup on three server and all of three replicate to each other , so what can i do to apply ha-proxy and how can it would be in clustered structure.

please give your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Hazelcast Clustering Plugin for clustering openfire. There is fully description how to step hazecast plugin in openfire read it https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/hazelcast/readme.html

You should take 2 or more openfire server with hazecast plugin , after that take a ha proxy server and add ip address of clustered openfire server.

+
sudo nano /etc/haproxy.cnf file and the following lines ;

global
        log /dev/log   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout     5000
        clitimeout     50000
        srvtimeout     50000

listen webfarm 
    bind 192.168.1.2:1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server openfire_anuj :5222 check
    server openfire_girish :5222 check
    server openfire_rahul :5222 check